# REST: set ReadSecurity / WriteSecurity (Item Level Permissions)

Tags: permissions, rest, item

**Is it possible to set this with REST (or JSOM?)**

(these are not exposed as properties in List REST endpoint: [MSDN List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_List))

**I can set this:**

[image]

**with PowerShell**:

```
$spList.ReadSecurity=2 # 1=read all items, 2=read items created by user
$spList.WriteSecurity=4 # 1=Create and edit All, 2=Create and edit Own items, 4=None
```

Comment: There is at least one reason for which you should avoid item level permissions : it affects page load performance. Not only that, there is also a limit of 50000 unique permissions per site collection. You should probably consider a better alternative. Maybe use an event receiver.

Comment: I think this is a common misconception; This setting of Item Level _**Permissions**_ is **not** the same as Item Level _**Security**_, with the latter your Break Security  and use (custom) Permission Profiles (that's where the confusion starts with the word "*Permission*" having different meanings). Al the performance/50000 items comments are about Item Level _**Security**_

Comment: Created separate question on this threshold / security / permission: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173845/differences-between-item-level-permissions-and-item-level-security

Comment: ReadSecurity and WriteSecurity are included in the SchemaXML that can be requested using REST API but I don't see any way to update the values with REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to set or update **ReadSecurity** or **WriteSecurity** using **REST** **API** and **JSOM** both.

## REST API

*Request body*

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.List"
  },
  "ReadSecurity": 2,
  "WriteSecurity": 4
}
```

*End-point*

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{List Name}')
```

You need to make an `UPDATE` request to above end-point with above request body. I have tested it using My [SP REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd).

[image]

**More about ReadSecurity & WriteSecurity**

`ReadSecurity` & `WriteSecurity` do not appear in response when you make a `GET` request to the list end-point but it returns all properties those are mentioned in *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_List)*. I mean following end-point

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{List Name}')
```

But if use `$select` operator in your query, then you will get the value of `ReadSecurity` & `WriteSecurity`. I mean following

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{List Name}')?$select=ReadSecurity,WriteSecurity
```

The reason is: these (`ReadSecurity` & `WriteSecurity`) properties are not returned with the resource. See more on [Getting properties that aren't returned with the resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx#NavigationProperties).

## JSOM

Set value using

```
yourList.set_readSecurity(2)
yourList.set_writeSecurity(4)
```

Get value using

```
yourList.get_readSecurity()
yourList.get_writeSecurity()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apperently only works in SharePoin online, it does NOT work for ON PREM

Answer (score 1):

While the OP asks specifically for a REST or JSOM approach, there is another JavaScript option (which wraps the REST API anyway) using [PNPJS](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/) and is compatible with SP Online.
Adding this answer for completeness.

```
await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").update({ ReadSecurity: 2, WriteSecurity: 2 } as IListInfo); //Sets to only allow users to set and read their own list items.
```